# What is the best way to fmod a decimal number?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, double

My problem is getting most accurate result from a mod calculation, I'm getting a remainder answer to do another rounding calculation, so I do need a accurate result to do so.

`double a = 0.12345678...(may with many digits);`

`double b = fmod(a, 0.01);`

the result `b` may be inaccurate deal with the binary storing issue.

Do I have to consider using `float` to increase the accuracy.
Or I just move the digit from decimal point to integer

`double a = 12345678.0;`

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "accurate" ; precision or approximation?

Comment: i think is precision or any proper way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

First, any serious implementation of fmod will answer the floating point nearest to the remainder in single/double/whatever precision as if the division were performed with infinite precision.
(***NOTE***: rephrased thanks to @EricPostpischil)

Though, that's well too late. The binary floating point internal representation of 0.01 does not represent 1/100 exactly as you already seem to know.

Let's examine how the error cumulates.

You want to know the remainder of a division, say `a % b = c`.

You have inexact representations a1 and b1, and you know an error bound for these representations: `a1=a+ea1`, `abs(ea1) < ea`, `b1=b+eb1`, `abs(eb1) < eb`.

What can you say about `a1 % b1 = c1` (the exact operation), `c1=c+ec1` that is about error bound `abs(ec1) < ec`?

```
a = q * b + c.
a1 = q1 * b1 + c1.
a+ea1 = (q+eq1)*(b+eb1) + (c+ec1).
ea1 = eq1*(b+eb1) + q*eb1 + ec1.
ec1 = ea1 - q*eb1 - eq1*(b+eb1).
ec >= max( ea , abs(q)*eb , eq*abs(b) , eq*eb).
ec <= ea + abs(q)*eb + eq*abs(b) + eq*eb.
```

You can control `ea` and `abs(q)*eb` by increasing precision of representation (single, double, extended, quadruple, arbitrary precision...).

But the important term in this equality is `eq*abs(b)`, because if quotient can be off by one, then the bound of error is `ec > b` !

And of course, quotient can be off by one, such cases is extremely easy to construct.
Take `c=0` and `a1` a representation off `a` by default (`ea1<0`) or `b1` a representation off `b` by excess (`eb1>0`) and you're done, you get `eq1 = -1` even for small quotient and accurate precision.

Don't think that carefully controlling rounding modes such as to obtain `ea1 > 0` (excess) and `eb1 <= 0` (default) would protect you in all cases, since we can construct the inverse case where

```
b - smallValue < c < b
```

Don't try `remainder` a variant of `fmod` that rounds the quotient rather than truncate, that will just move the problem near perfect tie (when the exact division a/b is a multiple of 1/2).

With a carefull analysis of error bounds, you could answer an estimate of `ec` and identify the bad cases of potentially incorrect rounding of quotient `q` (when `a1/b1` is near a whole int), or `abs(q)*eb` reaches 1, or `ea>=b`.

In bad cases, you could arrange to raise an exception, and restart producing `a1` and `b1` with increased precision, but in edge case `c=0`, there is no guaranty of convergence, even with arbitrary precision.

Comment: A proper `fmod` implementation does not just return the representable value to the remainder; it returns the exact remainder. In IEEE 754, the mathematical remainder is always representable, so the nearest representable value is always correct. (The mathematical remainder is either the dividend or has greatest and least significant bits that are not outside the greatest and least significant bits of the divisor. Therefore it is representable.)

Comment: There is a typo in the above comment; the first sentence should say “… the representable value **nearest** to the remainder;…”,

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I think part of aka's point was that if one wants to compute the modulus with regard to the *actual* number 1/100 (as opposed to the `double` represented by 0.01), using `fmod` with a divisor of `0.01` isn't going to yield that; I think a better approach would be to extract the fractional part and then divide by 100.

Comment: @supercat: How can the first sentence have that interpretation? `fmod(x, .01)` cannot in general return the nearest representable value to the remainder of `x` when divided by 1/100. E.g., if `x` is 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375, then `fmod(x, .01)` is zero, which is not the nearest representable value to 0.00000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's clear from the standard that the expression `fmod(x,0.01)` as written would compute the modulus relative to the fraction (5764607523034235/576460752303423488).  What's I would regard as unclear if I were reading the code is whether it was *intended* to compute the modulus relative to that fraction, or relative to the fraction 1/100.  I would be very unhappy seeing that expression code unless comments made clear why the former meaning was intended.

Comment: @supercat: My first comment is not about the rest of the code in the answer. It is about the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand your question correctly , you want the results of `fmod` in `double`. As described by Pascal Couq in comments that `fmod` prototype is `double fmod(double x,double y);` you can do it like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  double a = 12.1649232848373633242;
  double b = 1.234;
  double c;
  setbuf(stdout,NULL);
  c = fmod(a,b);

  printf("%.13f",c);//.13 in the format specifiers here describes the number of decimal places upto which you want to get the value .
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The prototype of `fmod` is `double fmod(double x, double y);`. I do not think that casting the result to `double` achieves anything (and I know more than I would like to about floating-point arithmetic in C).

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes absolutely sir, actually I thought its result may be system dependent, so I was directly casting the value without even thinking about this way. Anyway thanks for your suggestion , updated my answer. :) :)

Comment: @PascalCuoq I am unable to understand OP's question fully but I tried to answer his part ,"is there any proper way to do it". :)